# How do you validate an array in Joi with only one item?

Tags: joi

I would like to accept an array of strings as an argument with Joi but when I pass only one item I receive the error value `must be an array`. If I try to pass a second value that's empty to force array syntax conversion in Express I receive `must be one of...` error after defining the strict set of possible values as empty is not strictly allowed.

Request schema:

```js
const requestSchema = Joi.object().keys({
  query: Joi.object().keys({
    endTime: Joi.string().required(),
    fields: Joi.array().items(
      Joi.string().valid(
        "value1",
        "value2",
        "value3"
      )
    ),
    startTime: Joi.string().required()
  })
});
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this question?

Answer (score 2):

The key here is the `single()` function. Implementing this will allow you to pass a single value for an array and Joi will wrap the single value in an array so that it validates correctly:

```js
const requestSchema = Joi.object().keys({
  query: Joi.object().keys({
    endTime: Joi.string().required(),
    fields: Joi.array().items(
      Joi.string().valid(
        "value1",
        "value2",
        "value3"
      )
    ).single(),
    startTime: Joi.string().required()
  })
});
```

This allows you to send `fields=value1` which gets converted to: `fields: ["value1"]`.

Comment: What if I want to match one of the schemas and if that matches the object ignore another schema? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74658952/joi-validations-if-object-matches-the-schema-validate-against-it-from-multiple